# Syntax highlighting, lang-objc and objc not a language?

Tags: discussion, syntax-highlighting

According to comments in [Revisions to What is syntax highlighting and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/184109/revisions):

> There is no "objc" keyword. Please don't add things unless you actually know for sure.

Prior to adding the "objc", I tested it on a live questions. The syntax highlighting worked. (Sorry, I don't recall the question that it was verified).

Why would syntax highlighting work if there's no "lang-objc"?

Answer (score 1):

The [objc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objc) tag is a synonym for [objective-c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/objective-c).

If you navigate to [the tag wiki page for the latter](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/objective-c/info), you will notice the language used for syntax highlighting is plain C (at the bottom of the page):

[image: C language used for highlighting Objective-C code]

That probably "works" because C-style syntax highlighting can be applied to Objective-C without introducing too many problems.